# Google Places API: Text Search does not return rating field in results anymore

Tags: google-maps, google-api, google-places-api

A few days ago I ran the following query: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=amusement+parks+in+delhi&key=API_KEY`.

This returned some results which I could then display in a list view.
But, today when I ran the program again, I noticed that the `rating` field in the response was missing. Due to this the ratings in the list view was null for all list items. Few days ago the same had a numeric rating which was being displayed for every list item.

Unfortunately, I don't have the screenshots of the previous version's response and I wasn't aware that such a situation could arise. Currently, this is the response I get from text search.

[image: Text search response]
Due to this, the resulting application.
[image: Resulting List View]

So, is it possible that google changed their API responses somehow?

If so, shouldn't they notify the users?

Is there any way I can fix this, without using place details API call?

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem. I am using both Place Search and Text Search - my app was working fine a couple of days ago but suddenly the ratings are all gone.

I fixed it by using a workaround - use Place Details after getting the place and then grab the answer from there. Although, it requires an additional API call, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue yesterday. Today is working again without changing anything on my side. Might somebody at Google messed up things :-P

Comment: This is really not an answer. It would be an OK comment; but just claiming "this happens" ... doesn't solve any real issue.

Comment: Yes, it seems it was a problem on their side. The response now contains the rating field.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be currently a bug in the Places API: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62788930